# Spring security LDAP connection

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-security

Hello i am new to spring. 
I am trying to connect to ActiveDirectory from my server using Spring-security1.3.0 spring2.0.1. 
I am using the documentation [example](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html) (18.4.5)
I can see the the LdapAuthenticationProvider object is constructed at page load in the
 application-context.xml. 
few Questions:
I wonder where and when will the answer from the Active directory returns?
I think i should see the result in UserDetails object. but how to see this? what code does this?
My goal is to get the user role from the Active directory and search my DB(in my server) what this role is permitted to do. So i would like to know what object contains the role of the user. 
thanks,

Comment: I guess you meant spring-security 3.1.0.. right?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

to see, if any roles (authorities) have been added to the current user (authentication). This should work no matter how you authenticate/authorize your users.

Spring security is a great framework for securing your applications. However, for everything a little bit more complex than the demos, it's best to get a good "feeling" for the basics first. Try to get an understanding how everything works together, before you implement something non-trivial like an LDAP-DB-based solution. It might take some time at first, but it definitely pays off.